# Timing paralelized numpy calculation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, time

I have a simple pi-approximating script like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

start = 10
stop = 1000000
step = 100
exactsolution = np.pi


def montecarlopi(N=1000000):
    random_x = np.random.random(size = N)
    random_y = np.random.random(size = N)
    bod = np.array([random_x, random_y]).T
    square_area = N
    quarter_circle_area = np.count_nonzero(np.linalg.norm(bod, axis = 1)<=1)
    pi_approx = 4*quarter_circle_area/square_area
    return pi_approx


if __name__ == '__main__':
    times = []
    results = []
    attemps = np.arange(start = start, stop = stop, step = step)
    for i in attemps:
        start_time = time.time()
        results.append(montecarlopi(i))
        times.append(time.time()-start_time)

    absolute_errors = np.abs(np.array(results)-exactsolution)
```

and I want to know how long the calculation takes based on the number of random attemps I use. As you can see I use a for loop to get each of the calculation times I need, but this defeats the purpose of Numpy, slowing down my code a lot. Effectively I'd like to just call `montecarlopi()` on the whole `attemps` array, but then I wouldn't have the calculation times.

Is there a way to time each paralelized calculation numpy does?

Answer (score 0):

I used the timing code from the answer provided here:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165245/plot-timings-for-a-range-of-inputs

I only had to change `labels` to `codecs` in the line:

```
empty_multi_index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[], []], codes=[[], []], names=['func', 'result'])
```

#### Timing linear

Then you can run your whole timing experiment using

```
timings.plot_times([montecarlopi], inputs=np.arange(10, 1000000, 1000), repeats=3)
```

And get an output like this

[image: Timing monte carlo pi]

#### Timing Logspace

Or more clear using logspacing

```
timings.plot_times([montecarlopi], inputs=np.logspace(1, 8, 8, dtype=np.int), repeats=3)
```

[image]